# Function within requestanimationframe() called too many times, how to call only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, observable, requestanimationframe

I currently have a script in which I am tracking the .offset() position of an element. When this element reaches the top, left, bottom, or right edge of the window, I need to call a function, which should only be called once, and would then be called again the next time it hits the edge of the window.

Right now I have this:

```
var exceededBounds = false

function checkPosition(element) {
 var pos = element.offset(); 
 var maxBoundsX = $(window).width();
 var maxBoundsY = $(window).height();
 var minBoundsX = 0
 var minBoundsY = 0

 // if the element hits one of the edges of the window
 if (pos.left >= maxBoundsX || pos.top >= maxBoundsY || pos.left <= minBoundsX || pos.top <= minBoundsY) {
  if (!exceededBounds) {
   exceededBounds = true
  }
  else {
   exceededBounds = false
  }
 }
 else {
  exceededBounds = exceededBounds;
 }
}

function something() {
 // do something here, which only happens once
}


function init() {
 checkPosition(element);
 if (exceededBounds) {
  something()
 }
  requestAnimationFrame(init);
}

requestAnimationFrame(init);
```

The problem is, the something() function is called multiple times, I believe due to the frame rate of requestanimationframe() ? I need to use requestanimationframe, however I only want to call the something() function essentially when the variable exceededBounds changes. I thought about trying to implement some kind of observe thing here, but it felt too complex for what I actually need.

Thanks

Comment: have u tried putting `exceededBounds = false;` inside `if (exceededBounds)` ? this way you will keep checking the position of the element with  `checkPosition(element);` but `something()` will only run when `exceededBounds` is set to `true` again inside `checkPosition(element)`

Comment: Approach is wrong. Don't use `requestAnimationFrame()`. Use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep two booleans:

- `exceeding` to know if your element is currently out of bounds.
- `changed` to know if at last check it was already exceeding or not.

```js
var element = $('#el');
var changed = false;
var exceeding = false;

function checkPosition(element) {
  var pos = element.offset();
  var maxBoundsX = $(window).width();
  var maxBoundsY = $(window).height();
  var minBoundsX = 0
  var minBoundsY = 0

  // if the element hits one of the edges of the window
  if (pos.left >= maxBoundsX || pos.top >= maxBoundsY || pos.left <= minBoundsX || pos.top <= minBoundsY) {
    if (!exceeding) {
      changed = true
    } else {
      changed = false;
    }
    exceeding = true;
  } else {
    if (exceeding) {
      changed = true;
    } else {
      changed = false;
    }
    exceeding = false;
  }
}

function something() {
  console.log('changed:', exceeding ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
  // do something here, which only happens once
}


function init() {
  checkPosition(element);
  if (changed) {
    something()
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(init);
}

requestAnimationFrame(init);
```

```css
#el {
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 30px);
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

#cont {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">
  <div id="el">Scroll me</div>
</div>
```

Now, I don't know what is causing your element to move in **your** scenario, but don't poll like that. Instead, listen to the event that may cause this change. E.G, in my snippet, you would listen to a throttled `scroll` event.

```js
var element = $('#el');
var changed = false;
var exceeding = false;

cont.onscroll = throttle(init);

function checkPosition(element) {
  var pos = element.offset();
  var maxBoundsX = $(window).width();
  var maxBoundsY = $(window).height();
  var minBoundsX = 0
  var minBoundsY = 0

  // if the element hits one of the edges of the window
  if (pos.left >= maxBoundsX || pos.top >= maxBoundsY || pos.left <= minBoundsX || pos.top <= minBoundsY) {
   // our if else blocks can also be replaced by
    changed = !exceeding;
    exceeding = true;
  } else {
    changed = !!exceeding;
    exceeding = false;
  }
}

function something() {
  console.log('changed:', exceeding ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
  // do something here, which only happens once
}


function init() {
  checkPosition(element);
  if (changed) {
    something()
  }
}
// wait for next screen refresh before triggering event's callback
function throttle(callback) {
  if (typeof callback !== 'function')
    throw 'A callback function must be passed';
  var active = false;
  var evt;
  function handler() {
    active = false;
    callback(evt);
  };
  return function handleEvent(e) {
    evt = e;
    if (!active) {
      active = true;
      requestAnimationFrame(handler);
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#el {
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 30px);
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

#cont {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">
  <div id="el">Scroll me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I understand this. The only issue now is that the something() function is called twice...I only want to call something() once (which I will use to change the style of an element), until the element exceeds the bounds again (when the style will change again)

Comment: @biscuit_ I don't really get what you are saying. If you only want to fire `something` when it is going out of bounds, then in `init` call `if( changed && exceeding ) { something(); }`

Answer (score 0):

something() *will* be called multiple times if the element is ever has `exceededBounds`, unless your `something` immediately changes the element immediately so that it's within bounds - that's how recursively calling requestAnimationFrame works, it'll just keep getting called over and over again.

I'd suggest altering `something` such that the element is immediately altered so as to make it within bounds again - then, `something` will only run once (until it goes out of bounds again).

Comment: Hmm, I can't really change the element immediately, to push it back within the bounds, as I need to animation to be natural (I am actually using a CSS animation to move the element also, so I cannot use the raw values controlling it).